# update featured image after wp.media will be chosen - wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have my own options page in wordpress backend and there I am listing posts from one specific post type. Plus, I have an option to change posts's featured image.

With below code I'm opening Media Library and choosing the image.

```
<div class="logoBox">
    <?php
    $upload_link = esc_url( get_upload_iframe_src( 'image', $item->ID ) );
    $supplier_img_id = get_post_meta( $item->ID, '_thumbnail_id', true );
    $supplier_img_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $supplier_img_id, 'full' );
    $img_success = is_array( $supplier_img_src );
    ?>
    <a class="changeSupplierImage <?php if ( $img_success  ) { echo 'hidden'; } ?>" href="<?php echo $upload_link ?>">
        <?php if ( $img_success ) : ?>
            <img src="<?php echo $supplier_img_src[0] ?>" alt="<?php echo $item->post_title; ?>" />
        <?php endif; ?>
    </a>
    <input class="custom-img-id" name="custom-img-id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $supplier_img_id ); ?>" />
</div>

jQuery(".changeSupplierImage").each(function(){
    jQuery(this).click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var frame,
            imgContainer = jQuery(this),
            imgIdInput = jQuery(this).parent().find( '.custom-img-id' );

        if ( frame ) {
          frame.open();
          return;
        }

        frame = wp.media({
            title: 'Select or Upload Media Of the Supplier',
            button: {
                text: 'Use this media'
            },
            multiple: false
        });

        frame.on( 'select', function() {
            var attachment = frame.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
            imgContainer.html( '<img src="'+attachment.url+'" alt="" />' );
            imgIdInput.val( attachment.id );
            var ajaxurl = "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"; 
            var attachmentUrl = attachment.url;
            var postId = jQuery(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().find(".currentSuppPostId").val();
            $.ajax({ 
                type: 'POST',
                url: ajaxurl,
                data: {
                    action: 'update_featured_image', 
                    attachmentUrl: attachmentUrl,
                    postId: postId
                }, 
                success: function (data) {

                }
            });
        });
        frame.open();
    });
});
```

And, how you see, for updating featured image, I added ajax call with "update_featured_image" function which is doing below:

```
function update_featured_image(){
    $postId = $_POST['postId'];
    $attachmentUrl = $_POST['attachmentUrl'];
    update_post_meta($postId, '_thumbnail_id', $attachmentUrl);
}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_update_featured_image', 'update_featured_image');
add_action('wp_ajax_update_featured_image', 'update_featured_image');
```

But this is not updating my featured image, instead it is empty. Any idea?

Comment: Any ideas please?